# Transparency isn't drawing in canvas

Tags: android

Good day to everyone!

```
Drawable drawable = contex.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_image);
drawable.setBounds(rect);
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

When I use an auto-created "app_icon.png", transparency is drawing great. But when I use the same code for my own image with transparency (created in GIMP) all transparency is replaced with white color.

What could be wrong?

Comment: are you using .png extension itself?

Comment: @droidhot, yes, images I've created have a .png extension and loaded to res/drawable folder. You asked about that?

Comment: have you created the image on transparent background in GIMP? I mean there's something like "fill in" under "Advanced options" when you try to create a image in GIMP

Comment: @manjusg, when I edited those images, I've added an alpha layer and erased all background. In image-viewers and in preview background is transparent.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because by default gimp saves the colour (white here) of transparent pixels. Try telling it not to do that (it's an option when you save).

Comment: Yes, that option was turned on. I've re-saved images with turning that option off, dropped new images to the project and cleaned the project, and still got that white color on background.